# Where is my instance variable in Object?

Tags: ruby, object

Why can't I see `@obj.instance_variables` in `Object` when `method_missing` is invoked?

```
module Arena
  class Place
    def initialize obj
      @obj = obj
      method_missing_in_obj
      @obj.instance_variable_set(:@unit, '10')
      puts @obj.instance_variables
      yield @obj
    end
    def method_missing_in_obj
      def @obj.method_missing method, *args, &blk
        puts @obj.instance_variables
        super
      end
      self
    end
  end
end

Arena::Place.new(Object.new) do |obj|
  puts obj.instance_variable_get(:@unit)
  puts obj.foo
end
```

`$> ruby test_me.rb`:

```
=> @unit
=> 10
=> in `method_missing': undefined method `foo' for #<Object:0x007fd89b1c96e0 @unit="10"> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a subtle bug! The problem is that you're calling `@obj.instance_variables` when you define `@obj.method_missing`. Remember, that defines a method in `@obj`'s singleton class, so when you use `@obj` inside the method definition, you're asking for `@obj`'s instance variable `@obj` which is `nil` (and `nil` has no instance variables).

All you need to do is remove the explicit receiver, since `@obj` is implicitly the receiver for methods defined in its singleton class.

```
def method_missing_in_obj
  def @obj.method_missing method, *args, &blk
    puts instance_variables
    super
  end
  self
end
```